# Cannot debug program in CLion editor

Tags: c++, windows, clion, jetbrains-ide

While trying to debug C++ program using CLion editor following error appears and debugging does not hit any debug point.

What this error means and how to fix this problem?

```
Could not initialize class com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.WinPipe
```

Comment: Sounds like something got corrupted. Reinstalling might fix the issue. Usually there's a stacktrace associated with an error that's being printed out. Are you sure that's the entire error message?

Comment: Problem solved after Invalidate Caches.Thanks.